# Continuum Fallacy with regards to arbitrary categories

Tags: fallacies

Is it a continuum fallacy to say that categories don't *actually* exist because *most* things exists in a continuum? (if at all)

When talking about "human life", it is clear to me that a bunch of cells doesn't start being a "human" at any particular point, so the idea of "human" is merely a human construct and only to be seen as such. (hence embryo is no more or less human than a baby).

When talking about "*life*", there's a strict (but mostly arbitrary?) [set of rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Life#Biology) to what constitutes a living thing (some basic traits that all that is considered living must have).
So at least in that sense, *life* is well-defined.

But this (arbitrary?) definition of life leaves out things like viruses and [prions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prion), and can include to things like computer worms and Jupiter's red spot ([as it eats other storms and spits out other storms](http://www.slate.com/blogs/bad_astronomy/2008/07/17/jupiters_red_spot_chews_up_and_spits_out_a_storm.html)) and non-carbon possibly really weird and abstract life forms.

I'm inclined to conclude doesn't exist in any real sense, rather it is the label we attach to some fuzzy set of things, mostly arbitrarily.

So my question is, am I committing a Continuum fallacy?

Considering this [take](https://www.logicallyfallacious.com/tools/lp/Bo/LogicalFallacies/58/Argument-of-the-Beard):

> Categories are human constructs that we create to help us make sense
>   of things, yet they often end up creating more confusion by tricking
>   us into thinking abstract concepts actually exist

I agree with this, but I somehow feel this contradicts calling it a fallacy in the first place.

Wouldn't it simply mean that there are indeed no categories in actuality, that *most*  things exists in a spectrum, and lines just don't really exist? (hence arbitrary?)

I recognize though that some strict and well-defined categories do exist in physics, for example (protons vs neutrons), but these are the exception in terms of categories and not the rule.

p.s.: I mean no offence on the whole embryo thing, that just happens to be my view on the matter, I have a clear distinction between true and practical in my mind.

Comment: *Categories* are clearly constructs (of the human mins ? maybe... in the sense that they are built-in into our "mental hardware" ?) but can we avoi them ? The name ["red"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red) is clearly an "arbitrary definition" for a certain wavelenght in the  visible spectrum of light,   but do you think that we can communicate something intelligible with statements like: "I want an apple reflecting light with approximately 625–740 nanometers wavelenght" ?

Comment: Conclusion: it si not a *fallacy* at all: we cannot speak (think ?) without "categories", i.e. abstract terms.

Comment: I think it is clear categories are helpful in communication, but I don't think formal arguments can be made if they rest on them. 

For instance, it's one thing to say that there's this thing we call "red" and another that "red" is somehow special in a way "blue" isn't.

Same with "it's one thing to say that there's this thing we call "life" and another that "life" is somehow special in a way "dead" isn't."

Comment: You are.  Vagueness means there is no boundary, not that distinctions themselves are nonexistent.  We can productively discuss green and blue, even if there is no boundary between them.  Since we use them, they remain useful distinctions and not meaningless constructs.  Usage implies meaning, whether or not the meaning takes the form you might prefer.  Individual concepts may not be separable, but they play roles and therefore exist.  You cannot have a clear distinction between practical and true if you hold the stated view, as they also have no specified boundary between them.

Comment: Isn't it possible to say argue that what is 'true' *is* regardless of human experience, but 'practical' isn't? 
The fact that there are wavelengths of light distinguishable from one another is true, regardless of human experience, to call some arbitrary range red, is not. The same could be said about gravity.

It's funny you should mention "Green and Blue" in particular, since for a very long time there was no historical difference between the two. 
Would that mean "Blue" wasn't "true" until "Blue" became a thing?

Comment: It is possible, but not in any convincing way.  Why would what is outside human experience have a truth value at all?  We invented those.  Conventions are real things that exist and they don't disappear just because they are imperfect.

Comment: I think that really depends if you fall under "Realism" or not. I would think the universe would still exist regardless of our existence, and as such things will continue to be, and that what *is*, can be regarded as true.
I grant however, that it is not so clear if "true" exists outside of human experience, but I don't see why not. It becomes a chicken and egg problem, if we define "true" in such a way to be human-independent might be impossible as definitions themselves kind-of are.
The idea that "concepts exist" though, seems slightly platonic...